# Add "my account navigation"-link with extension on Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, extensions, navigation, link

I am writing an extension for Magento 1.9. This extension should add a link to my account navigation. It is working so far, but I have no idea where I can put my `vendor_module.xml` file what includes the `addLink` action.

This extension should be work with every Magento system and if I put the file on `app/design/frontend/*/*/layout` I have to decide for a design. But I do not know the name of the current design of the users.

Is there a folder where the rewrite surely takes place?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/129989/cms-page-with-customer-navigation-and-add-link-in-customer-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `base/default` folder is the folder where you should put all your module layout files.

This folder is the last folder where Magento fallback system will look for files.

Also as it is a core Magento folder it will never get deleted by Magento upgrades.

Comment: I used `vendor_module.xml`. I just edited it for the question. Your solution works well for me. I tried it before, but I got an empty file at the other design folder. I had to know that Magento will just look for one file.

Comment: @SimonSolutions you don't need an empty layout file with the same name in other theme folders, Magento will automatically find the one in `base/default` if it can't find it in the current theme.

Comment: I noticed my mistake of an empty file. Thank you!

Comment: @SimonSolutions no worries feel free to mark your question as answered so others will benefit from it.

Comment: I had to wait 15 minutes. Sorry about that.